# How to Sum last value of all users in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a database with different users, with an amount column....all this user all have different value in their amount colume, but i want to pick all the last amount for each user and sum it.

i tried it like this but game an error

```
 $returned =  DB::table('sales')->sum('returned')->last();
```

pls, i dont want the total sum of the amount column....because some users have more than one amount, so i want to pick the last one for each user and sum it

Comment: There is no `amount` column in your example, also it is not users table but `sales` table. Could you provide table structures, sample data and expected behavior ?

Comment: You probably want to do something like ```DB::table('sales')->select(DB::raw('sum(amount)'))->get();```

Comment: yes its sales table...i just want to get the last amount of everyone in sales table and sum it

Comment: pls, i dont want the total sum of the amount column....because some users have more than one amount, so i want to pick the last one for each user and sum it

Comment: Can you please provide your `sales` table structure

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
DB::table('sales')->latest()->get()->unique('user_id')->sum('returned');
```

if you have sales Model use

```
Sales::latest()->get()->unique('user_id')->sum('returned');
```

**Note the code is updated**